# TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'w'

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, tuples, iterable-unpacking

Code is here

`return self.activator(reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, map(lambda x, w: x*w, zip(input_vec, self.weights)), 0.0) + self.bias)`

The python2.7-version code is like `lambda (x, w)`

But now the Tuple parameter unpacking was removed 
so I dont know how to figure it :(

Comment: If i get you right, you see that map expects a function with just one element. If you map a list of tuples, you can get the values with indices.
x = (13, 37)
print(x[0], x[1])

Comment: emmmmm I cant get what you mean.The argument of w is still not enough

Comment: @yizhui liu you shouldn't use x and y as parameters but only one parameter and indices in the function-body. I made an answer with the code for that. Hope that helps. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49632316/4667743)

Comment: Please clarify: I think you mean you're using Python 3, and since tuple-unpacking was removed, you can no longer declare a lambda fn whose input is a tuple as `lambda (x, w)` and automatically get its input arg unpacked into `x,w`. Right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a good thing to make a small running example which shows the problem. In your case, that is not the fact since we are missing some variables.  Like i said in the other comment, your list you map over is made of tuples. Like you already know, you cannot unpack the tuples anymore, but you can use indices like you would use on an array. A simple working example:

```
val = reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, map(lambda t: t[0]*t[1], zip([10, 20, 30], [0.1, 0.3, 0.7])), 0.0)
print(val)
```

Like you see, the lambda function passed to the map function just has one parameter now. I called it t to make clear that this is a tuple, you can call it x if you want. In the function-body i use indices to get the first and second element of the tuple. If you run this code, you see that it works. So next step is to adept that to your code:

```
return self.activator(reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, map(lambda t: t[0]*t[1], zip(input_vec, self.weights)), 0.0) + self.bias)
```

And that should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

you can't unpack anymore. But, you can just take tuple as it is, and use indexing in the formula:

```
map(lambda t: t[0]*t[1], zip(input_vec, self.weights))
```

using `map` with `lambda` has little interest, generator comprehension equivalent:

```
(x*w for x,w in zip(input_vec, self.weights))
```

(and unpacking works)

The same construct needs to be repeated with the outer `lambda` and even `reduce`, which can be completely eliminated with `sum` which performs sums of the elements:

```
return self.activator(sum(x*w for x,w in zip(input_vec, self.weights)) + self.bias)
```

no more lambdas, shorter and clearer